# How do I remove 'open with code' from my context menu for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, shell-extensions

I have uninstalled Visual Studio Code, but the "open with code" option is still in my context menu when I right click a folder.

If I install VS Code again, it will keep the old option and adds a second entry which opens VS code.

[image: Context menu with "open with code"]

Comment: Related: [How to remove items from the right click (context) menu in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/5011/358766)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/) will help you to modify registry.

Most of the menu items that used for all files and folders can be found at one of these keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell    
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers    
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx
```

Comment: Thanks!! it was in the first link. I was looking for it on the second one.

Answer (score 5):

I used [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) to find the offending records (there were several)  and optionally disable them. You can then right click and select properties on the "Open with code" rows to find the registry paths. With that info I could delete the relevant keys from the registry manually. One was `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\Ticino\Command` but there were others.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I got here searching for those exact terms.

You may also find right click options here:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\

You can also move them to shift+right click as per this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1332589