# How to restore "Open with Code" windows shell inegration

Tags: visual-studio-code

Once VSCode is installed, is there any way to enable/disable windows shell integration options pointed below:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove 'open with code' from my context menu for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579181/how-do-i-remove-open-with-code-from-my-context-menu-for-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @TimothyG., I know that I can manually add/remove items from shell. Can I get a confirmation if VSCode is able to integrate itself with shell after the installation?  I am hoping there is a command line or a ctrl-shift-p option

Comment: @TimothyG. in addition, consider the registry edit option answer created in 2015, 7 years ago. I expect we see some improvement in the area after 7 years.